# How to explain from $\alpha_n=\beta_{n-1}\alpha_{n-1}$ to get $\alpha_n=\beta_{n-1}\cdots \beta_{1}\beta_{0}$ mathematically

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, recurrence-relations

Let $\alpha_n, \beta_n\in\mathbb{C}$, $n\geq 0$. Suppose that $\alpha_n=\beta_{n-1}\alpha_{n-1}$ for $n\geq 1$. How would you explain from this that
$$
\alpha_n=\beta_{n-1}\cdots \beta_{1}\beta_{0}
$$
for $n\geq 1$? The problem is that, for example, we have
$$
\alpha_n=\beta_{n-1}\alpha_{n-1}=\beta_{n-1}\beta_{n-2}\alpha_{n-2};
$$
the first step holds for $n\geq 1$, while the second step holds for $n\geq 2$. So this expression holds for $n\geq 2$ overall. If one keeps doing like that way, one gets the desired result, though for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Use induction over $n$.

Comment: Since the naturals are well-ordered, it only takes a finite number of steps to get to $\alpha_0$ if you keep going backwards. So, recursive methods like this work. (This, of course, is only true if $\alpha_0=1$).

Comment: The result is not true. You have to add the condition $\alpha_0=1$ if you want to make it hold.

Comment: Apparently $\alpha_0=1,$ it has to be added. As for the expression $\alpha_n=\beta_{n-1}\cdots \beta_{1}\beta_{0},$ it is a usual mathematical notation.

Comment: OK. That settles it. I'll use induction over $n$, didn't think of that way. Yes, there should have been $\alpha_n=\beta_{n-1}\cdots \beta_1\beta_0\alpha_0$. Sorry for typo!